How can I get mouse events that were generated by another program (NonMouse)?
NonMouse (https://github.com/takeyamayuki/NonMouse) is an application that tracks finger movement to move your cursor accordingly
I made a Python script to track the coordinates of the mouse
However, when I run the NonMouse, my Python script doesn't track the cursor movement (probably because it tracks when the mouse itself move, not the cursor)
How can I get the script to track the cursor's coordinates when I'm using the application?
Here is my Python script:
from pynput import *
import os

def get_coords(x, y):
    os.system('cls')
    print("X:", x)
    print("Y:", y)
    if (840 <= x <= 1080) and (460 <= y <= 620): print("Idle")
    elif (840 <= x <= 1080) and (y <= 460): print("Forward")
    elif (840 <= x <= 1080) and (620 <= y <= 1080): print("Back")
    elif (x <= 840) and (y <= 540): print("ForwardLeft")
    elif (1080 <= x <= 1920) and (y <= 540): print("ForwardRight")
    elif (x <= 840) and (540 <= y <= 1080): print("BackLeft")
    elif (1080 <= x <= 1920) and (540 <= y <= 1080): print("BackRight")
    
with mouse.Listener(on_move = get_coords) as listen:
    listen.join()

Context: I made this script so that it tracks where the cursor is and sends the texts in the print commands to tell an Arduino RC car where to go. My screen is 1920x1080. I'm dividing the screen into parts and printing whatever the area's assigned name is when the cursor goes into it.
The NonMouse application can be downloaded in here:
https://github.com/takeyamayuki/NonMouse/releases
Thank you to anyone who might help!
Summary
Expectation:
Get application to move cursor and script to track cursor's coordinates while I move it
Reality:
Script doesn't work when I'm using the application to control the mouse
